# How do you add a click event handler to the vertical axis of a BarChart in FLEX?

Tags: apache-flex, mouseevent, charts, flex-charting

Does anyone know if it is possible to add a click event handler to the vertical axis (or any axis) of a barchart in flex? 
If I add the handler to the BarChart itself, it looks as though the event doesn't fire unless you click on the actual chart, not the axes.
Any help is appreciated, if you need more info let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

set verticalAxis property to some implementation of mx.charts.chartClasses.IAxis and add a mouse click event listener to it.

Comment: Nishu: That's what I'm doing. Setting the verticalAxis property to an instance of CategoryAxis(). Tried adding a listener for MouseEvent.CLICK on the CategoryAxis and it isn't firing. I already have a listener for ChartItemEvent.ITEM_CLICK on the BarChart itself, and that doesn't fire either when you click on the axis labels.

Comment: @Deviation yeah Doesn't seem like you can do it. You can add event listeners to label and title of axis though.